# Appropriate destructor for my own custom-made Arraylist (C++)

Tags: c++, arrays, templates, destructor

On my windows machine, I don't receive any warnings/errors but on a Linux machine I do (I don't remember what it was exactly). I only call the destructor in the end of my program.

Here's a sample.

Header

```
 template<class T> 
 class CustomArray {
   T *someArray;
   int numElements;

   CustomArray<T>();
   ~CustomArray<T>();
 }

 //destructor
 template<class T>
 CustomArray<T>::~CustomArray() {
   for(int k=0; k<numElements;k++)
     someArray[i].~T();
   delete [] someArray;
 }
```

main

```
 int main() {
   CustomArray<int> myArray;
   //initialize myArray
   myArray.~CustomArray();
   return 0;
 }
```

Is the there a problem with the destructor?

I appreciate the help.

Comment: You've got it backwards. The whole point of writing a destructor is so that you **don't** have to do anything special to free memory. It gets called automatically.

Comment: @john if the object is in automatic storage

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is. You don't call it manually (at least not in this case) - calling the destructor explicitly is only done in some corner cases.

You just need the `delete[]` inside the destructor and that's it - assuming of course `someArray` was allocated with `new[]`.

The `myArray` object is in automatic storage and will be deleted (and have its destructor called) automatically, at the end of the scope.

Comment: The constructor will initialize it (should have mentioned that). 

So what you're saying is, delete [] someArray, will delocate memory used for each instance of class T in the array on its own?